# new ReactiveDict() in meteor 1.2

Tags: javascript, meteor

I did an update to meteor 1.2. Also I changed the package to use 'react'.
But in the code I used

```
var anything = new ReactiveDict();
var something = new ReactiveVar();
```

How do I have to change that to use my code in the new meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the package first:

> meteor add reactive-dict

Comment: Oh, I thought it was summarized to react in meteor 1.2

Comment: No, the react package contains the reactjs support that is new in 1.2

Comment: and what about `new ReactiveVar();`? I still have to use reactive-var?